# Error while building apache syncope

Tags: apache, maven, ubuntu-16.04, apache-syncope

I tried to install apache syncope on my machine(ubuntu 16.04) according to this documentation.
[https://syncope.apache.org/building.html#Prerequisites][1]
I cloned the git repo and tried to build by using...

```
mvn clean install
```

Some installation happend but finally raised an error. It looks like this....

```
-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
Running org.apache.syncope.fit.cli.CLIITCase
Tests run: 8, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 74.142 sec - in org.apache.syncope.fit.cli.CLIITCase
Running org.apache.syncope.fit.console.AjaxBrowseITCase
Tests run: 4, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 20.808 sec - in org.apache.syncope.fit.console.AjaxBrowseITCase
Running org.apache.syncope.fit.console.AjaxPalettePanelITCase
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.001 sec - in org.apache.syncope.fit.console.AjaxPalettePanelITCase
Running org.apache.syncope.fit.console.AjaxTextFieldITCase
Tests run: 4, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.003 sec - in org.apache.syncope.fit.console.AjaxTextFieldITCase
Running org.apache.syncope.fit.console.AnyObjectsITCase
Tests run: 4, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 18.317 sec - in org.apache.syncope.fit.console.AnyObjectsITCase
Running org.apache.syncope.fit.console.AnyTypeClassesITCase
Tests run: 4, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 15.733 sec - in org.apache.syncope.fit.console.AnyTypeClassesITCase
Running org.apache.syncope.fit.console.AnyTypesITCase
Tests run: 4, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 8.887 sec - in org.apache.syncope.fit.console.AnyTypesITCase
Running org.apache.syncope.fit.console.BulkActionITCase
Tests run: 7, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 44.265 sec - in org.apache.syncope.fit.console.BulkActionITCase
Running org.apache.syncope.fit.console.DisplayAttributesITCase
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.905 sec - in org.apache.syncope.fit.console.DisplayAttributesITCase
Running org.apache.syncope.fit.console.GroupsITCase
Tests run: 5, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 23.918 sec - in org.apache.syncope.fit.console.GroupsITCase
Running org.apache.syncope.fit.console.LogsITCase
Tests run: 4, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 3.603 sec - in org.apache.syncope.fit.console.LogsITCase
Running org.apache.syncope.fit.console.NotificationsITCase
Tests run: 5, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 15.384 sec - in org.apache.syncope.fit.console.NotificationsITCase
Running org.apache.syncope.fit.console.ParametersITCase
Tests run: 4, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 6.092 sec - in org.apache.syncope.fit.console.ParametersITCase
Running org.apache.syncope.fit.console.PoliciesITCase
Tests run: 14, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 51.494 sec - in org.apache.syncope.fit.console.PoliciesITCase
Running org.apache.syncope.fit.console.RealmsITCase
Tests run: 5, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 12.745 sec - in org.apache.syncope.fit.console.RealmsITCase
Running org.apache.syncope.fit.console.RelationshipTypesITCase
Tests run: 4, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 6.225 sec - in org.apache.syncope.fit.console.RelationshipTypesITCase
Running org.apache.syncope.fit.console.ReportsITCase
Tests run: 4, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 8.956 sec - in org.apache.syncope.fit.console.ReportsITCase
Running org.apache.syncope.fit.console.RolesITCase
Tests run: 4, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 8.797 sec - in org.apache.syncope.fit.console.RolesITCase
Running org.apache.syncope.fit.console.SchemasITCase
Tests run: 5, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 14.867 sec - in org.apache.syncope.fit.console.SchemasITCase
Running org.apache.syncope.fit.console.SecurityQuestionsITCase
Tests run: 4, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 4.546 sec - in org.apache.syncope.fit.console.SecurityQuestionsITCase
Running org.apache.syncope.fit.console.TopologyITCase
Tests run: 11, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 28.318 sec - in org.apache.syncope.fit.console.TopologyITCase
Running org.apache.syncope.fit.console.UsersITCase
Tests run: 7, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 66.721 sec - in org.apache.syncope.fit.console.UsersITCase
Running org.apache.syncope.fit.core.AnyObjectITCase
Tests run: 10, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 8.851 sec - in org.apache.syncope.fit.core.AnyObjectITCase
Running org.apache.syncope.fit.core.AnyTypeClassITCase
Tests run: 5, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 1.945 sec - in org.apache.syncope.fit.core.AnyTypeClassITCase
Running org.apache.syncope.fit.core.AnyTypeITCase
Tests run: 8, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 1.166 sec - in org.apache.syncope.fit.core.AnyTypeITCase
Running org.apache.syncope.fit.core.AuthenticationITCase
Tests run: 11, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 18.085 sec - in org.apache.syncope.fit.core.AuthenticationITCase
Running org.apache.syncope.fit.core.CamelRouteITCase
Tests run: 5, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 3.007 sec - in org.apache.syncope.fit.core.CamelRouteITCase
Running org.apache.syncope.fit.core.ConfigurationITCase
Tests run: 8, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.841 sec - in org.apache.syncope.fit.core.ConfigurationITCase
Running org.apache.syncope.fit.core.ConnectorITCase
Tests run: 16, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 3.827 sec - in org.apache.syncope.fit.core.ConnectorITCase
Running org.apache.syncope.fit.core.DerSchemaITCase
Tests run: 7, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.487 sec - in org.apache.syncope.fit.core.DerSchemaITCase
Running org.apache.syncope.fit.core.DomainITCase
Tests run: 4, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.252 sec - in org.apache.syncope.fit.core.DomainITCase
Running org.apache.syncope.fit.core.ExceptionMapperITCase
Tests run: 3, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 1.955 sec - in org.apache.syncope.fit.core.ExceptionMapperITCase
Running org.apache.syncope.fit.core.GroupITCase
Tests run: 26, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 28.472 sec - in org.apache.syncope.fit.core.GroupITCase
Running org.apache.syncope.fit.core.LoggerITCase
Tests run: 9, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.423 sec - in org.apache.syncope.fit.core.LoggerITCase
Running org.apache.syncope.fit.core.MailTemplateITCase
Tests run: 4, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.265 sec - in org.apache.syncope.fit.core.MailTemplateITCase
Running org.apache.syncope.fit.core.MembershipITCase
Tests run: 4, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 8.309 sec - in org.apache.syncope.fit.core.MembershipITCase
Running org.apache.syncope.fit.core.MigrationITCase
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 10.335 sec - in org.apache.syncope.fit.core.MigrationITCase
Running org.apache.syncope.fit.core.MultitenancyITCase
Tests run: 5, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 1.896 sec - in org.apache.syncope.fit.core.MultitenancyITCase
Running org.apache.syncope.fit.core.NotificationITCase
Tests run: 9, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.292 sec - in org.apache.syncope.fit.core.NotificationITCase
Running org.apache.syncope.fit.core.NotificationTaskITCase
Tests run: 9, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 17.131 sec - in org.apache.syncope.fit.core.NotificationTaskITCase
Running org.apache.syncope.fit.core.PlainSchemaITCase
Tests run: 15, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 10.067 sec - in org.apache.syncope.fit.core.PlainSchemaITCase
Running org.apache.syncope.fit.core.PolicyITCase
Tests run: 11, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 1.097 sec - in org.apache.syncope.fit.core.PolicyITCase
Running org.apache.syncope.fit.core.PropagationTaskITCase
Tests run: 5, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 7.417 sec - in org.apache.syncope.fit.core.PropagationTaskITCase
Running org.apache.syncope.fit.core.PullTaskITCase
Tests run: 18, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 169.353 sec - in org.apache.syncope.fit.core.PullTaskITCase
Running org.apache.syncope.fit.core.PushTaskITCase
Tests run: 10, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 42.503 sec - in org.apache.syncope.fit.core.PushTaskITCase
Running org.apache.syncope.fit.core.RESTITCase
Tests run: 4, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 6.759 sec - in org.apache.syncope.fit.core.RESTITCase
Running org.apache.syncope.fit.core.RealmITCase
Tests run: 6, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 3.468 sec - in org.apache.syncope.fit.core.RealmITCase
Running org.apache.syncope.fit.core.RecertificationITCase
Tests run: 1, Failures: 1, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 11.335 sec <<< FAILURE! - in org.apache.syncope.fit.core.RecertificationITCase
recertification(org.apache.syncope.fit.core.RecertificationITCase)  Time elapsed: 11.23 sec  <<< FAILURE!
java.lang.AssertionError: Timeout when executing task e95555d2-1b09-42c8-b25b-f4c4ec598989
    at org.apache.syncope.fit.core.RecertificationITCase.recertification(RecertificationITCase.java:35)

Running org.apache.syncope.fit.core.RelationshipTypeITCase
Tests run: 4, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.002 sec - in org.apache.syncope.fit.core.RelationshipTypeITCase
Running org.apache.syncope.fit.core.ReportITCase
Tests run: 11, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 37.735 sec - in org.apache.syncope.fit.core.ReportITCase
Running org.apache.syncope.fit.core.ReportTemplateITCase
Tests run: 4, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 2.024 sec - in org.apache.syncope.fit.core.ReportTemplateITCase
Running org.apache.syncope.fit.core.ResourceITCase
Tests run: 23, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 28.139 sec - in org.apache.syncope.fit.core.ResourceITCase
Running org.apache.syncope.fit.core.RoleITCase
Tests run: 6, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 2.432 sec - in org.apache.syncope.fit.core.RoleITCase
Running org.apache.syncope.fit.core.SchedTaskITCase
Tests run: 6, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 8.008 sec - in org.apache.syncope.fit.core.SchedTaskITCase
Running org.apache.syncope.fit.core.SearchITCase
Tests run: 24, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 25.887 sec - in org.apache.syncope.fit.core.SearchITCase
Running org.apache.syncope.fit.core.SecurityQuestionITCase
Tests run: 5, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.576 sec - in org.apache.syncope.fit.core.SecurityQuestionITCase
Running org.apache.syncope.fit.core.SwaggerITCase
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 1.309 sec - in org.apache.syncope.fit.core.SwaggerITCase
Running org.apache.syncope.fit.core.UserITCase
Tests run: 40, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 174.256 sec - in org.apache.syncope.fit.core.UserITCase
Running org.apache.syncope.fit.core.UserIssuesITCase
Tests run: 33, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 192.494 sec - in org.apache.syncope.fit.core.UserIssuesITCase
Running org.apache.syncope.fit.core.UserSelfITCase
Tests run: 12, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 36.865 sec - in org.apache.syncope.fit.core.UserSelfITCase
Running org.apache.syncope.fit.core.UserWorkflowITCase
Tests run: 3, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 18.585 sec - in org.apache.syncope.fit.core.UserWorkflowITCase
Running org.apache.syncope.fit.core.VirAttrITCase
Tests run: 10, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 61.432 sec - in org.apache.syncope.fit.core.VirAttrITCase
Running org.apache.syncope.fit.core.VirSchemaITCase
Tests run: 5, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 1.406 sec - in org.apache.syncope.fit.core.VirSchemaITCase
Running org.apache.syncope.fit.core.WorkflowITCase
Tests run: 4, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 2, Time elapsed: 1.574 sec - in org.apache.syncope.fit.core.WorkflowITCase

Results :

Failed tests: 
  RecertificationITCase.recertification:35->AbstractTaskITCase.execTask:124 Timeout when executing task e95555d2-1b09-42c8-b25b-f4c4ec598989

Tests run: 518, Failures: 1, Errors: 0, Skipped: 2

[INFO] 
[INFO] --- cargo-maven2-plugin:1.6.2:stop (stop-container) @ syncope-fit-core-reference ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- modernizer-maven-plugin:1.5.0:modernizer (modernizer-check) @ syncope-fit-core-reference ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-failsafe-plugin:2.19.1:verify (default) @ syncope-fit-core-reference ---
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO] 
[INFO] Apache Syncope ..................................... SUCCESS [ 22.846 s]
[INFO] Apache Syncope Common .............................. SUCCESS [  1.051 s]
[INFO] Apache Syncope Common Lib .......................... SUCCESS [ 51.213 s]
[INFO] Apache Syncope Common REST API ..................... SUCCESS [  6.444 s]
[INFO] Apache Syncope Core ................................ SUCCESS [  0.988 s]
[INFO] Apache Syncope Core Persistence API ................ SUCCESS [  4.391 s]
[INFO] Apache Syncope Core Provisioning API ............... SUCCESS [  2.455 s]
[INFO] Apache Syncope Core Workflow API ................... SUCCESS [  1.104 s]
[INFO] Apache Syncope Core Spring ......................... SUCCESS [01:38 min]
[INFO] Apache Syncope Core Persistence JPA ................ SUCCESS [02:20 min]
[INFO] Apache Syncope Core Workflow Java .................. SUCCESS [  7.300 s]
[INFO] Apache Syncope Core Provisioning Java .............. SUCCESS [ 51.038 s]
[INFO] Apache Syncope Core Workflow Activiti .............. SUCCESS [  8.639 s]
[INFO] Apache Syncope Core Logic .......................... SUCCESS [  4.874 s]
[INFO] Apache Syncope Core REST CXF ....................... SUCCESS [ 31.352 s]
[INFO] Apache Syncope Core Migration ...................... SUCCESS [  1.078 s]
[INFO] Apache Syncope Client .............................. SUCCESS [  0.489 s]
[INFO] Apache Syncope Client Lib .......................... SUCCESS [ 16.490 s]
[INFO] Apache Syncope Client Console ...................... SUCCESS [ 19.772 s]
[INFO] Apache Syncope Client CLI .......................... SUCCESS [ 19.527 s]
[INFO] Apache Syncope Client Enduser ...................... SUCCESS [  2.248 s]
[INFO] Apache Syncope FIT ................................. SUCCESS [  0.563 s]
[INFO] Apache Syncope FIT Build Tools ..................... SUCCESS [ 43.163 s]
[INFO] Apache Syncope Extensions .......................... SUCCESS [  0.437 s]
[INFO] Apache Syncope Extensions: Camel ................... SUCCESS [  0.478 s]
[INFO] Apache Syncope Extensions: Camel Common Lib ........ SUCCESS [  0.846 s]
[INFO] Apache Syncope Extensions: Camel REST API .......... SUCCESS [  2.703 s]
[INFO] Apache Syncope Extensions: Camel Persistence API ... SUCCESS [  1.526 s]
[INFO] Apache Syncope Extensions: Camel Provisioning API .. SUCCESS [  0.934 s]
[INFO] Apache Syncope Extensions: Camel Provisioning ...... SUCCESS [  2.583 s]
[INFO] Apache Syncope Extensions: Camel Logic ............. SUCCESS [  2.295 s]
[INFO] Apache Syncope Extensions: Camel REST CXF .......... SUCCESS [  2.610 s]
[INFO] Apache Syncope Extensions: Camel Client Console .... SUCCESS [  1.391 s]
[INFO] Apache Syncope Extensions: Camel Persistence JPA ... SUCCESS [  1.586 s]
[INFO] Apache Syncope Extensions: Swagger UI .............. SUCCESS [  1.707 s]
[INFO] Apache Syncope FIT Core Reference .................. FAILURE [27:53 min]
[INFO] Apache Syncope FIT Console Reference ............... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Syncope FIT Enduser Reference ............... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Syncope Archetype ........................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Syncope Standalone Distribution ............. SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Syncope Deb ................................. SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Syncope Deb Core ............................ SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Syncope Deb Console ......................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Syncope Deb Enduser ......................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Syncope Installer ........................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Syncope IDE ................................. SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Syncope IDE Eclipse ......................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Syncope IDE Eclipse Plugin .................. SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Syncope IDE Eclipse P2 Site ................. SKIPPED
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 37:56 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2017-03-03T13:15:53+05:30
[INFO] Final Memory: 156M/498M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-failsafe-plugin:2.19.1:verify (default) on project syncope-fit-core-reference: There are test failures.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Please refer to /home/govinda/github_repos/syncope/fit/core-reference/target/failsafe-reports for the individual test results.
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command
[ERROR]   mvn <goals> -rf :syncope-fit-core-reference'
```

What should I do?

Comment: Hi, the message is clear `There are test failures.`, but without other information is not possible to understand the problem, we should read the full maven output.
For further questions please refer to the mailing list at https://syncope.apache.org/mailing-lists.html

Comment: Hi more detail has been added.

Answer (score 0):

Please note that:

> You do not need to clone Apache Syncope if you want to build your IdM
>   with Syncope!

For getting start with Apache Syncope I suggest you to follow [Create Maven Project](https://syncope.apache.org/docs/getting-started.html#maven-project). Note that you can customize and replace your source code everywhere very easy. See [Reference Guide](https://syncope.apache.org/docs/reference-guide.html#customization).

However, clone and build from GitHub has another settings that you can find [here](https://syncope.apache.org/building.html).